# javascript click image display

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, divider

What I'm  trying to do is, when one of six divs is clicked, a separate div will have 3 specific divs appear in it. Each of the original six divs have three similar but different divs related to it.

http://jsfiddle.net/petiteco24601/hgo8eqdq/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".talkbubble").mouseout(function(){
        $(".sidebar").show();
});$
    $(".talkbubble").click(function(){
        $
```

How do I make it so that when you click a "talkbubble" div, a different "sidebar" div appears with all its contained elements, and when  you mouseout, the first talkbubble div automatically activates?

Comment: Why so many `$(document).ready(function() {` ?

Comment: your code does not compile..you have a syntax error

Comment: You should really stop and look at your code's formatting and correctness. You have syntax errors, nested document.ready functions, and it's indented poorly. Clean code is step one on a path to success. Use the TidyUp button in your Fiddle, then check out jslint.

Comment: You should "beautify" (i.e. format) your code, so that you could easier see that there is at least one `}` missing ;-)

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/dztf9pLp/

Comment: @Logan: Damn, beat me too it!

Comment: There is a lot of `$('.big-image')` and `$('#big-image-'+id)` in JS but they don't exist in the html ...

Comment: Have seen enough to vote for closing. I'm just curious to know the reason for the upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demo of how to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/n1xb48z8/2/

The main part of this example is some javascript that looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    showSideBar(1);
    $('.expander').click(function(){
        var sidebarIndex = $(this).data('sidebar-index');
        showSideBar(sidebarIndex);
    });
    $('#Container').mouseleave(function(){
        showSideBar(1);
    });

});

function showSideBar(index){
    $('.sidebarContent').hide();
    $('.sidebarContent[data-index="' + index + '"]').show();
}
```

.data('some-name') will get you the attribute data-some-name="" on the specific element, this is a html 5 attribute and if you do not want to use it you can instead give each of the elements their own class names such as:

```
<div class="sidebarContent subBarContent_1">
    <!-- content -->
</div>
```

and use the '.subBarContent_1' as your jquery selector instead. You would then also have to have some sort of data attached to your clickable divs to identify which one you wanna show, you could use a hidden field to do that like:

```
<input type="hidden" class="subContentSelector" value="subBarContent_1" />
```

The javascript for that looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    showSideBar(1);
    $('.expander').click(function(){
        var sidebarSelector = $(this).find('.subContentSelector').val();
        showSideBar(sidebarSelector );
    });
    $('#Container').mouseleave(function(){
        showSideBar('subBarContent_1');
    });

});

function showSideBar(selector){
    $('.sidebarContent').hide();
    $('.sidebarContent.' + selector).show();
}
```

Ps. the overflow:hidden css is because chrome was messing up the placement of the sidebar content otherwise... oh chrome, you silly goose

Comment: Oh my goodness thank you! Your code actually made a lot of sense. My only question is, would there be some reason, other than personal preferance, to not rely on the HTML5? I've tried using the data-index method on an older version of DreamWeaver and when I try to view it from DreamWeaver in the browser(Chrome), it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm glad to help! :) The main reason why not to use HTML5 is if your site/application have to be run on very old systems. Some companies still use windows XP as their OS of choice because they need to use applications still not available on the vista/7/8. I do not know how many users still use these old systems, but a project i worked on 2 years ago had to be run-able on windows XP and some old version IE because of "other applications not available on newer systems". If your users are assumed to all have modern browsers then you should use HTML5 =) (Mobile browsers "all" support HTML5 btw)